# PXDBTimeSpanLongAttribute to accept a negative time

Tags: acumatica

We have a few needs to have a time field in Acumatica (PXDBInt as total minutes) to show the value to the user and allow the user to enter in a negative value. The standard formatting of the PXDBTimeSpanLong attribute doesn't allow a negative value to be entered or correctly displayed (db value or unbound formula value is negative already).

Has anyone created a custom class that inherits `PXDBTimeSpanLongAttribute` and been able to get a negative value to display and be entered? We are using the `TimeSpanFormatType.ShortHoursMinutesCompact` format which displays in hh:mm

**Example user entries:**

- "01:30" *(1 hour and 30 minutes)*
- "-02:45" *(negative 2 hours and 45 minutes)*
- "00:05" *(5 minutes)*

**Sample DAC usage for PXDBTimeSpanLongAttribute:**

```
public abstract class myTime : PX.Data.IBqlField
{
}
[PXDBTimeSpanLong(Format = TimeSpanFormatType.ShortHoursMinutesCompact)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "My Time")]
public virtual Int32? MyTime { get set; }
```

**Testing the formatting using ShortHoursMinutesCompact**

- A positive value between "00:00" (int 0) and "23:59" (int 1439) works correctly
- A negative number while stored in the database correctly is not correctly displayed (assuming the entry allows for negative entry). For example an expected "-02:45" (int -165) value results in a display of " 0:2 ". When I click in the field then click out the value is changed to "00:02" without entering any new value.
- There is no field restriction from entering in a value greater than 24 hours even though the intent of the ShortHoursMinutesCompact format is a 24 hour entry. The field will allow and accept any value that fits the hh:mm format (values between "00:00" and "99:99"). When the user enters for example "29:00" the displayed value is changed to "05:00" but the database value is 1740 (29 hours as total minutes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found a workaround**

While I need the `PXDBTimeSpanLongAttribute` to accept negative values for all allowable formats I was able to solve the more important issue for my requirement of needing a negative value 24 hour time field (which validates the entry within -24 to +24 hours).

I found `PXTimeListAttribute` is a working version of `PXDBTimeSpanLongAttribute` (when using the `ShortHoursMinutesCompact` format).

**Benefits of using PXTimeList vs PXDBTimeSpanLong (ShortHoursMinutesCompact)**

- Using an int data type - no need to change the database field type. *(Need to include the PXDBInt attribute with PXTimeListAttribute vs before PXDBTimeSpanLong was both)*
- Allows for both positive and negative numbers
- Restricts the entry from within +/- 23:59

In a perfect world it would be nice to allow -24:00 to +24:00 but topic for another day.

In addition to changing the attribute used on my DAC/field I had to update the page entry for my field from a PXMaskEdit to PXTimeSpan using the following example:

*Page grid - RowTemplate*:

```
<px:PXTimeSpan ID="edMyTimeField" TimeMode="True" runat="server" DataField="MyTimeField" InputMask="hh:mm" CommitChanges="True" />
```

*Page grid - Columns*:

```
<px:PXGridColumn DataField="MyTimeField" Width="60px" AutoCallBack="True" RenderEditorText="True"/>
```

Sample usage of the attribute:

```
#region MyTimeField
public abstract class myTimeField : PX.Data.IBqlField
{
}
[PXDBInt]
[PXTimeList]
[PXDefault(0)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "My Time")]
public virtual Int32? MyTimeField { get; set; }
#endregion
```